# Python add dataframe column using lookup codes returning blanks

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe, lookup

I'm trying to add a new column to a Python dataframe using a lookup code. I've tried several methods, but the new columns always returns as blank.

My large dataframe has the column

```
file:
input_code
20
21

20
```

(note some blank rows), and my lookup dictionary is:

```
lookup = {'20':'1' , '21':'4', '22':'3'}
```

I've tried several different suggestions I've found in other examples such as:

```
file['output'] = file['input_code'].map(lookup)

file['output'] = np.where(file['input_code']=='21','4','')

file['output'] = file['input_code'].map(lambda x: lookup.get(x,np.nan)
```

as well as trying to join/merge a dataframe version of the lookup dictionary. None of these throw out any errors, but all of them return file['output'] as a column of NaN's.

The only thing I can think is that it's to do with data types - the dtype of file['input_code'] is an object, but I'm not proficient enough to know the specifics, and any attempt I make to change the dtype also doesn't seem to work.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `apply()`?

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(['20', '21', '', '22'], columns=['input_code'])
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)

lookup = {'20': '1', '21': '4', '22': '3'}

df['output'] = df.input_code.apply(lambda x: lookup.get(x, np.nan))
print(df)
```

**Results:**

```
  input_code
0         20
1         21
2           
3         22

input_code    object
dtype: object

  input_code output
0         20      1
1         21      4
2               NaN
3         22      3
```

Comment: Still no joy. As with the others, it adds the 'output' column but they're all blank.
On the dtypes for the dataframe, it gives input_code as object, but output as float64. Is this part of the issue?

Comment: If you run my test code, does it work?  If so, then you clearly have a dtype or format issue.  I would suggest that you try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Failing that (likely I expect) try to determine what in your data does not allow creating a MCVE.  Good Luck.